# Array affected after sending it to a function

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I send an arrey with the length of 26 twice to a function like this:

```
    ....
    SaveXML strXmlItem, DFCCM, SCTM, Zieltabelle
    SaveXML strXmlItem, DFCCS, SCTS, Zieltabelle
    ....
```

After the first invokation:

```
SaveXML strXmlItem, DFCCM, SCTM, Zieltabelle
```

Content of `strXmlItem` are changed. This array  with other variablesis definedlike this:

```
Dim strSql, strXmlItem(), strA2l, strHex As String
```

and the function is:

```
 Private Function SaveXML(strarr(), DFCC As String, SCT As String, ByVal Zieltabelle As String)
        strarr(4) = DFCC
        strarr(6) = SCT

         For K = 0 To UBound(strarr)
          MsgBox strarr(K)
        Next K

        'XML-Syntax anpassen
        For J = 1 To conAnzahlFelder - 1
          strarr(J) = MakeQuotes(strarr(J)) & ", "
        Next J
        strarr(conAnzahlFelder) = MakeQuotes(strarr(conAnzahlFelder)) & ")"

        ' Anfügeabfrage zusammenbasteln
        strSql = "Insert Into " & Zieltabelle & " ("
        For J = 1 To conAnzahlFelder
          strSql = strSql & "f" & Trim(CStr(J - 1)) & ", "
        Next J
        strSql = strSql & "f" & Trim(CStr(conAnzahlFelder)) & ") "
        strSql = strSql & "Values ("
        For J = 1 To conAnzahlFelder + 1
          strSql = strSql & strarr(J - 1)
        Next J

        MsgBox strSql
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
      End Function
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of issues in your code. But to answer your question

first:

try:

```
Private Function SaveXML(ByVal strarr(), DFCC As String, SCT As String, ByVal Zieltabelle As String)
```

instead of

```
Private Function SaveXML(strarr(), DFCC As String, SCT As String, ByVal Zieltabelle As String)
```

Google for the difference between ByVal and ByRef.

Second:

you really should use Option Explicit on the beginning of each module. You use a lot of undeclared variables. This can cause additional issues.

Third:

```
Dim strSql, strXmlItem(), strA2l, strHex As String
```

generates only ONE string variable (strHex). The others are declared as Variant if you use that Syntax. This works in some other languages but not in VBA!

and last but not least:

you declare a Function but you do not return any value for it. Either you do not want to return something (then you shouldn't declare it as Function) or you should provide a return value.

Comment: well ... that's bad. Then I guess you have to use a Collection instead of the Array. It's not so easy to deal with a Collection but provides more flexability and if I remember right, it can be passed ByVal